# Can a static variable can be used in data binding?

Tags: java, android, android-databinding

I tried to bind a static variable from my data model to the respective view using data binding. Does data binding allow static variables to bind? If so then how it is done? I even tried to access that static variable using a getter method.

The error is as follows

> cannot generate view binders java.lang.ClassCastException: class
> android.databinding.tool.expr.IdentifierExpr cannot be cast to class
> android.databinding.tool.expr.StaticIdentifierExpr
> (android.databinding.tool.expr.IdentifierExpr and
> android.databinding.tool.expr.StaticIdentifierExpr are in unnamed
> module of loader java.net.URLClassLoader @59fc7e39)

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the line of code which resulted in this exception? 
it would help to provide the perfect solution. Thanks!

Comment: Is it also possible for you to add the code of that static variable? & Is this a Gradle error?